# Can platform iOS version in Cocoapods not match deployment target?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Can I have my Podfile using `platform: ios, '7'` while my deployment target is set to iOS 8.0? Will there be any issues if I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should always build the libraries you're linking with against the SDK platform you're releasing on.  Although libraries (Pods) built for iOS 7 may work for iOS 8, you might see warnings or errors in when linking with them that they use deprecated  or SDK methods that are unavailable in iOS 8.